# Plots of Likelihood and log-likelihood function of Bernoulli random variable

Tags: r

```
data(quilpie, package = "GLMsData"); names(quilpie)
mu = seq(0.01, 0.99, length.out = 100L)
loglik = NULL
lik =NULL
for (i in 1:length(mu)) {
  loglik[i] <- sum(dbinom(quilpie$y, size = 1, prob=mu[i], log=TRUE))
  lik[i] <- sum(dbinom(quilpie$y, size=1, prob=mu[i], log=FALSE))
}
plot(mu, lik, type = "l", lwd = 2,
     xlab = expression(paste(,mu ,)),
     main = "Likelihood function",
     ,ylab = expression(paste("loglik (", mu ,")")))
abline(v = mu[which(lik==max(lik))], lwd = 3, lty =2)
abline(v = optimize(lik, lower = 0, upper = 1, maximum = TRUE)$max)
optimize(lik, lower = 0.01, upper = 0.99, maximum = TRUE)
mu[which(lik==max(lik))]

plot(mu, loglik, type = "l", lwd = 2,
     xlab = expression(paste(,mu ,)),
     main = "Log-likelihood function",
     ,ylab = expression(paste("loglik (", mu ,")")))
abline(v = mu[which(loglik==max(loglik))], lwd = 3, lty =2)
abline(v = optimize(loglik, lower = 0, upper = 1, maximum = TRUE)$max)
optimize(loglik, lower = 0.01, upper = 0.99, maximum = TRUE)
mu[which(loglik==max(loglik))]
```

I am trying to obtain plots for both the likelihood and the log-likelihood.
The log-likelihood plot works well but the likelihood function plot doesn't show anything.
Also, the *optimize* function doesn't work. I need help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the computations of `loglik` and `lik` as functions, vectorize them, then `optimize`. And plot with `curve`.

Note that the functions are to be optimized on the parameter `prob`, here as first argument, named `x`.
Argument `y` is the data.

```
floglik <- function(x, y){
  sum(dbinom(y, size = 1, prob = x, log = TRUE))
}
floglik <- Vectorize(floglik, "x")

max_loglik <- optimize(floglik, interval = c(0, 1), y = quilpie$y, maximum = TRUE)

curve(floglik(x, quilpie$y), from = 0, to = 1,
      lwd = 2,
      xlab = expression(paste(mu)),
      main = "Log-likelihood function",
      ylab = expression(paste("loglik (", mu ,")")))
abline(v = max_loglik$maximum)
```

And the same for the likelihood.

```
flik <- function(x, y){
  prod(dbinom(y, size = 1, prob = x, log = FALSE))
}
flik <- Vectorize(flik, "x")
max_lik <- optimize(flik, interval = c(0, 1), y = quilpie$y, maximum = TRUE)

curve(flik(x, quilpie$y), from = 0, to = 1,
      lwd = 2,
      xlab = expression(paste(mu)),
      main = "Likelihood function",
      ylab = expression(paste("lik (", mu ,")")))
abline(v = max_lik$maximum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the plot of the likelihood function prints out just a straight line instead of a curve which is not right.

Comment: @Quamena Apologies. I had copied&pasted from your code without realizing that the likelihood had `sum`. The likelihood is the *product* of the densities,  the *sum* comes from the `log`. Corrected now.

Comment: Is there a way to extract the variance/standard error of mu_hat?

Comment: names(max_loglik) only prints the maximum and the objective values.

Comment: @Quamena As for the variance, see [this CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191444/variance-in-estimating-p-for-a-binomial-distribution). And `optimize` returns a list with two members only. It's `optim` that returns more info.